# Accessing python libraries and functions using reticulate package in R

Tags: r, reticulate

I am working on python libraries and their functions in R environment using `reticulate` package.

I am accessing these libraries using the following criteria

```
library('reticulate')
pvlib <- import('pvlib')
```

models say from pvlib library can be obtained this way:

```
GFS <- pvlib$forecast$GFS
```

wherever I want this model, I can call it using the variable name in which I have stored it.

Now the problem lies in calling different function from libraries (for example `pvlib`).

I believe I can do it using the below mentioned way.

```
sandia_modules <- pvlib$pvsystem$retrieve_sam('sandiamod')
```

this approach isn't working for me. I am not sure how I can do it correctly. If anyone guide me to the correct approach will appreciate.

Regards

Comment: why is there a python tag?

Comment: because python and r users work with this sort of integration.

Comment: but if this question is in R, python only users (like myself) have nothing to say...

Comment: understand. Will take care now

Comment: Your code works for me (installed via `pvlib` via `pip`). What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @YuanTang I am getting error when I run `sandia_modules <- pvlib$pvsystem$retrieve_sam('sandiamod')` is that working well for you? Error is :  Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  invalid 'row.names' length`  and when I am running it's equivalent in python i.e `sandia_modules = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('sandiamod') ` it is working perfect. I am not sure why is it so

Comment: i just removed the package and installed again. It's working now. What stupid issue was it. I wasted so much time on this

Comment: @YuanTang this line of code worked. But now when I am running with other inputs like `cec_inverters = pvlib$pvsystem$retrieve_sam('sandiainverter')` I am getting the error: Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype' . Can you check if this working for you? and possibly what can be the issue now?